# Why is music for strings more likely to be in keys with sharps?

Tags: theory, instruments, key, key-signatures, orchestral-strings

One thing I've noticed is that music written for strings, such as violin concertos, are a lot more likely to written in a key like D or A major than something like F or Bb major. I recently saw a comic that confirms my suspicions:

[image: People call it the music version of xkcd]

Now, this does include both major and minor keys; a minor key has three fewer sharps than its parallel major key. But even if we shift over everything by 1 or 2 positions on the circle of fifths (as an average between 0 and 3), there is still a very obvious bias towards keys with sharps. Why does this phenomenon occur?

Comment: You mentioned "music written for strings", the chart is about conciertos. I did a brief check on string ensembles by Brahms, Schubert, and Schoenberg and I find plenty of keys with multiple flats. Also for Mozart, if you look at the Violin sonatas as well, i get the impression about half of them are in a key with flats. So I guess I'm saying, maybe this comic has a point, however, if you're seriously interested, you should try to systematically research it.

Comment: The same sort of phenomenon appears in guitar led songs. Mostly in sharp keys (unless the  guitar is tuned to Eb...) Whereas a lot of sax led songs are in flat keys.

Comment: It requires less mental reprograming between keys, because to play the flat version of an open string, you must go to the next lowest string (which is somewhat counter-intuitive...) whereas to play an open string half a step up you put your finger down a little closer to the nut than for a whole step, and no weird string change!

Comment: BTW, and not surprisingly, those are also the keys mostly used in solo classical guitar music (assuming B corresponds to B minor, and C-G to major)

Comment: Note the solo viola is tuned up a half step in Mozart's Sinfonia Concertante, so while the orchestra and solo violin are playing in E-flat major, the solo viola is effectively playing in D major.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Sharp-keys are in some ways nicer to play than flat ones.

The preference for these keys is perhaps most extreme in folk styles: going through two collections of celtic-style fiddle music<sup>[[978-1-85720-202-1](http://www.waltons.ie/home/products/view/11awal-1309cd-a-complete-guide-to-learning-the-irish-fiddle-cd-edition/)],[[1-871931-04-5](https://www.scotlandsmusic.com/Product/SM-J1NNFV/session-tunes-for-scottish-cellists)]</sup>, I found the distribution to be this crass:

- ♭♭ : 5
- ♭  : 5
- ♮  : 7
- ♯  : **57**
- ♯♯ : **70**
- ♯♯♯: 9

In particular D major is really a great favourite. In fiddle playing, this is also easy to explain: you want to use empty strings much more than in classical music. With more than two ♭s that's simply impossible on the high violin strings, but even for B♭, F, and C major the empty strings occur mostly on *thirds*. That is problematic, because these notes are the ones you need to do most intonation-adjustment on (upwards for leading notes, down for chords/double stops). In D major OTOH you have the fundamentals of the primary chords on the empty strings, which is perfect for droning etc.; while the thirds are all fingered and can be moved as necessary.

Now, empty strings are somewhat shunned in much of classical music, but in particular for solo playing (think the Bach Cello Suites!) they also have quite a significance. These are actually something of a counterexample though, with both Suite IV and V featuring 3 ♭s. However, since it's totally solo, you can much better "cheat": instead of adjusting the thirds, you adjust everything around them...

Otherwise, it's certainly a bit of a self-fulfilling truth: because the simple tunes are mostly in those keys, those are best practised, hence even advanced players may be a bit more firm in them than in ♭-heavy keys.

Comment: I think this is the way to do it, take a corpus of music and simply count. Your numbers certainly seem to suggest a strong preference for 2 sharps. One question though - wouldn't the consideration for playability with regard to the open strings apply equally well to D minor? Yet we see only 5 works with 1flat.

Comment: Yes, I'd reckon so. Personally I certainly find the minor keys till C or F to be quite nicely playable on the cello. But in folk playing in minor keys you use parallel major chords quite often (and major dominants much less), so I reckon the minor keys should be considered more like "use the major relative key, but end on the Tp" here, rather than "flatten the third, sixth and seventh degree".

Comment: One reason for this bias in folk could be the use of wind instruments that have a fixed key: a wind player should own a range of instruments in different keys but the most common key for a tin whistle or low whistle is D. Unlike a classical flute, these instruments do not have extra holes for playing in other keys.

Comment: @steveverrill: true, though at least for the tin whistle I reckon it's more the other way around: because the fiddlers like D major, let's build the whistles in that key!

Answer (score 16):

The answer is a relatively simple answer: it is easier for the violin an cello to play in those keys because of how the strings are configured. Look at this picture of a G scale on the violin:

[image]

As you can see, the G major scale fits very nicely on as the open strings notes make the scale extremely easy. Also because of the open string notes, many other sharp keys are easy to play like C, D, and A. It is also easy to use G#, D#, A#, and E#(F) because they are easy to grab because they are right next to the nut on the fingerboard.  When it comes to flat keys, they can be played on the violin and cello, but they lose open string options. For example, if you were playing in Ab major, the only open string you could take advantage of is G because Ab major contains Ab, Eb, and Db.

Comment: playing Devil's advocate here - you state its also easy to play G#,D# and A#.Then you say in Ab there's Ab and Eb,(and Bb) which are the same notes ! And where did E# come from (often called F) ?!

Comment: @Tim Actually, these notes are only the same on instruments with keyboards, and only since the well tempered clavier was invented. (I.e. Beginning of the 18th century.)

Comment: The differences are minimal though.

Comment: And with vibrato it's difficult to hear the actual note anyway.

Comment: @Tim the point kind of got lost, but I was trying to say that it is easy to use the open string and the notes right above them, but it is harder to grab the flat notes. I.e. if you want to play a Db you most likely wouldn't play it from the D string because it is higher on the finger board, but it would be easy to play D# on the D string.

Comment: @11684 That's....almost true. In all equal-tempered music (on a keyboard or not), enharmonically identical pitches are really and truly the same, pitch-wise. Also, "well-tempered" refers to a tuning system, not an instrument (and it's not actually a specific tuning system; there are various theories about which tuning(s) Bach preferred).

Comment: The difference is more pronounced on a cello.  With the hand in normal "first" position, it's possible to play each open string and the notes 2-5 half-steps above it.  The cello actually favors C and G over D, but things don't get too bad until one gets to the keys of A major or Eb major, which start having a mixture of notes in both lower and upper positions.

Comment: @Tim has a point regarding the notes close to the nut. If you are playing them in 1st position by lowering your 1st finger they are easier as flats because flats are about lowering while sharps are about raising; thus it is counter intuitive to lower a finger in order to raise a note. Of course it is possible to play a sharp with a low finger and often you need to do it, but it is not as logical as raising a finger when you want to raise a note.

Comment: Also, the intonation of sharps is done in relation to the note a half step above and the intonation of flats is done in relation to the note a half step below. Thus A sharp is intonated in relation to B, and B flat in relation to A. There can certainly be exceptions like intonation in relation to the harmony when playing with others, or intonation in relation to other notes on your violin like when playing double stops. But a general rule of thumb is as I wrote above.

Answer (score 6):

For stringed instruments such as the violin, playing in sharp keys (more accurately, 0 to 4 sharps) means making multiple main notes of the tonality coincide with open strings. This amplifies the instrument's show-off potential in two ways:

1. In fast passages, fingering is simplified because any time the melody touches on one of the four open strings, nothing needs to be fingered. Likewise for passages of triple and quadruple stops.
2. In expressive melodic passages, the sound is enriched by the open strings vibrating in resonance with the melody. For instance, play an A on the D-string of the violin (with a bit of vibrato if you like). You will see the A-string start to vibrate. Likewise, if you play a D on the A-string, the D-string will resonate (at its second partial) and the G-string will also resonate (at its third partial). These resonances linger slightly after a different note has been stopped on the original string and help to connect one note to the next.

D minor also works nicely for violin music in this regard (consider Bach's famous Chaconne from Partita no. 2). B minor also works, hence the three data points at B.

Answer (score 3):

On the acoustic guitar, the chords with the most open strings simply sound better and ring more beautifully. Because of this, the most beautiful chords on the guitar are E, A and G. As tonics, those are all sharp keys. E and A have a further advantage: they are often used together in songs because E is the dominant chord of tonic A, and A is the subdominant chord of tonic E. Another chord that happens to ring beautifully is D major as fingered on the three treble strings, and D is the dominant of G while G is the subdominant of D. D is a sharp key also. So many songs for guitar in rock, country and bluegrass are just naturally written in these sharp keys.

Comment: And by inference, string players often play in these styles that have guitars, which causes string players to often play in those same keys. Yes?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, because for sharps one can re-use the same string as for the natural note and just slide the finger for a half note shorter, so they are significantly easier than flats, where you have to use another string and finger string distance minus one half tone (minor fifth).

Comment: That is true for the open strings.It's as long as it is short for other notes.